# Auto fill file "creation" date in PyCharm

Tags: templates, pycharm

PyCharm provides several template variables, such as project name, user name, current date, etc.  I am looking for the variables of file "creation" date and time.  However, there seems no such variables.

Anyone knows how to automatically fill in the file creation date in PyCharm?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems you forgot to select the language that the template will be applicable, if you do so, no variables will popup in the variable edit menu.
Here is a step by step animated GIF:

[image]

- the $END$ variable makes the caret move to next new line after your defined template variables list, if, and only if the variables are automatically defined(like time, date, author...etc), and you must check the -skip if defined- checkbox in edit variables window, otherwise, the caret will move to the first undefined variable(description, todo, ...etc)

here is a good video from a guy nicknamed EggHead, I think he works with Intellij, checkout his daily playlist for jetbrain products  tweaks, shortcuts, settings, and of course his Anjularjs playlist, this guy 'John Lindquist' has an insane Anjularjs live edit development video.
check his channel

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxaVNGSax80